# Does maven surfire argLine override ./mvn/jvm.config?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, jvm-arguments

I have a project with the following ./mvn/jvm.config :

```
-Xms32g -Xmx64g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=20g
```

I was wondering if I configure my maven surfire plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xms12g -Xmx30g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=30g</argLine>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/RunMmoTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I know that my jvm.config will set the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable, but I can't find any documentation stating the precedence between MAVEN_OPTS and surfire `argLine`. Which one override the other? After running some tests, I have the feeling that the surfire `argLine` override whatever argument defined in `MAVEN_OPTS`. Is my guess correct??

Many thanks

Comment: First why are you using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin ? Really need memory settings like this for unit tests? Furthermore https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html. And running a build with 64GiB ? how many millions of modules do you use? What maven version/jdk etc. are you running?

Comment: I am working on the development of an in memory database and we run a bunch of test on/off heap that includes millions of input data that's why I need to run my tests using different memory set up. I am using: 
- Jdk 11
- maven 3.6.1

Comment: So this are integration tests which should be running via maven-failsafe-plugin also most recent should be used... so why using such old version of surefire? Cause 2.9 is about 9 years old ? I strongly recommend to use most recent versions ...

Comment: So why do you add memory settings to your command for maven which I have my doubts needs 64 G to build your project. In your tests you could do that but you should fork to use such things...

Comment: These are rather scaling than integration tests ^^. Regarding the surefire question, I can't really answer this I am not in the one maintaining these tests but I will recommend that the owner update to newer versions.
The 64G is not for maven to build the project, they are jvm options. Sorry if I mislead you I didn't provide the whole plugin config. Please check my updated

Comment: The `.mvn/jvm.config` is exactly for the JVM which is running the Maven build...

Comment: and the sunfire `argLine` are for the jvm running the tests?

Comment: In that sense if `argLine` does not define jvm options, will surfire forked jvm inherit the jvm options defined in .mvn/jvm.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If argLine does not define JVM options, will surefire forked jvm
>   inherit the jvm options defined in .mvn/jvm.config?

It will not. You may have completely different requirements for building the project than for running the tests.

Here the comment in [the source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/d8fe77d163a1da78b6eaaaadede1ad9d62eb5b31/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L412) of maven-surefire:

> For the default, the JVM will be a new instance of the same VM as the
>   one used to run Maven. JVM settings are not inherited from MAVEN_OPTS.

When we invoke the mvn command (`mvn.cmd` or `bin/mvn`) Maven reads and sets different environment variables and does it differently in Linux and Windows.

- On Linux, the `mvn` command [sets](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/a2b800de32cdb9adc1e64a43a0fc32e3ba878103/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn#L175) the `MAVEN_OPTS` variable by
  concatenating the existing  `MAVEN_OPTS` with the
  `$MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/.mvn/jvm.config` file and then invokes java
  [passing](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/a2b800de32cdb9adc1e64a43a0fc32e3ba878103/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn#L192) the `MAVEN_OPTS` as a parameter.
- On Windows, the mvn command [sets](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/da5d8b8f51839acfb02b30a9dabd88e5f7359141/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn.cmd#L163) `JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS` with the
  content of `jvm.config` and then invokes java [passing](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/da5d8b8f51839acfb02b30a9dabd88e5f7359141/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn.cmd#L172) `MAVEN_OPTS` and `JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS`

The surefire plugin forks a separate process for executing test by invoking `java` command but it will not pass the `MAVEN_OPTS` or `JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS` as parameters to JVM.

If you want to set the same JVM parameters for running test as for running maven then you can use ${parameters} in argLines. For example like this:

```
<configuration>
  <argLine>${MAVEN_OPTS}</argLine>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. After running different settings I can confirm that this is what I got :)